# React Invalid Hook call with Turborepo

Tags: reactjs, vite, turborepo

I have a setup made with Turborepo and pnpm (v7).

There's a package of the Monorepo called "UI" (which exports some React components) and another one for the web App (this one imports the components).

When some component that doesn't use hooks is imported from the web App there's no problem, but when it has a React Hooks (for instance, an useState) I got this error:

[image]

It seems that (according to [Documentation](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning)) this error has relation to:

- You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
- You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
- You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

But none of those reason is being happening here.

My `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file is this:

```
packages:
  - "apps/*"
  - "packages/*"
```

And `turbo.json` is this one:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build", "build:tw"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": []
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "storybook": {
      "cache": false,
      "dependsOn": ["dev:tw"]
    },
    "build:tw": {},
    "dev:tw": {
      "cache": false
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea of this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, i also run into the same error recently @pmiranda?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, and eventually found out that all the react dependencies across your apps and packages must be the same version to make this error to go away.